# Does anyone know how to give a pillager arrows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a command block that gives any pillager named "New_Moon_Soldier" full armor and a crossbow with quick charge 4, but for some reason when i name a pillager New_moon_Soldier, they don't have any arrows. I could give him arrows with /item but i don't know what slot to use for the command. Does anyone know the correct slot?

Comment: Mobs don't need arrows to shoot.

Comment: Well for some reason when i name the pillager New_Moon_Soldier he gets the crossbow but whenever he charges it up he just cant fully load it. Hell charge it up but then it just releases. It looks exactly like when a player tries to load a crossbow without any arrows

Comment: Try Quick Charge 3. The pillager AI might be having issues with such a quick charge time.

Comment: Nah I found the issue for some reason when you summon a mob with a different name it just removes all its items so you just have to summon them with items. I just used mcstacker and made the command from there